# How do I find commands that're available in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode

I know of 4 commands I can use in Vim's insert mode.

1. `C-w` delete word
2. `C-k` delete line
3. `C-d` delete one 'shiftwidth' worth of indent
4. `C-t` add one 'shiftwidth' worth of indent
5. `C-O` begin a [quick command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_command_in_insert_mode).

My results from googling have been saturated with answers on how to switch from insert mode to normal mode.

The page for `:help <C-d>` and the other insert mode commands is not what I'm looking for, it's always just the keystroke. How do I search for the specific commands available in insert mode? I don't know how to look it up...

---

More generally, how do I look up commands specific to a single mode?

Comment: Since you asked & answered as a community Q&A might want to generalize this to "How do I find commands that are available in a given mode?" and talk about `c_`, `v_` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the documentation you're looking for can be found on the `:help insert` page.

Everything you're looking for will be under [`:help ins-special-keys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html) section. As you can see from there, you can look up these commands using `:help` by prefixing the keystroke with a shorthand for the mode followed by an underscore - which is `i_` in this case.

Therefore, to look up what `<C-]>` does in insert mode is, type `:help i_CTRL-]`. To look up what `<C-]>` does in visual mode, type `:help v_CTRL-]`.

There is one exception to this, though. If you want to look up what a normal mode keystroke does, then you don't need to add a prefix. That's a design choice that I agree with. So just type `:help CTRL-]` to look up what `<C-]>` does in normal mode.

Comment: Why don't you need a `n_` prefix even though you're looking up a command in normal mode? It's vim documentation's philosophy. Vim docs focused more on ~giving quick useful information to the uninitiated~ rather than being a ~comprehensively engineered guide meant to be read cover-to-cover~. This decision DOES cause a bothersome lack of orthogonality in some cases (example: this answer), and repetition in others (example: an explanation on how to use the `'backspace' option` appears 4 times in [insert](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html)'s documentation).

Comment: This philosophic method towards documentation lowers the learning curve for beginners at the cost of people reading documentation cover-to-cover. Which is probably the right move ;)